# Write an Add Row with NewRow in one line

Tags: c#, datatable, newrow

I would like to add a new row in an existing table. I want to create a new row with the NewRow method and put the values on the same line.

```
DataTable dtTable1 = new DataTable();
dtTable1.Rows.Add(new DataColumn(NCdeTCMParametrs.NombreCol1), typeof(string));
dtTable1.Rows.Add(new DataColumn(NCdeTCMParametrs.NombreCol2()), typeof(string)); 
        
        
dtTable1.Rows.Add(dtTable1.NewRow() { new object[] { datCol1, string.Join(",", listCol2) } });
```

I can't find the correct syntax for it to be accepted. What is the mistake?

Comment: Why don't you use this overload ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.add?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRowCollection_Add_System_Object___

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`DataRowCollection.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.add?view=net-5.0) that takes an `Object[]`:

```
dtTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] { datCol1, string.Join(",", listCol2) });
```

[`DataTable.NewRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=net-5.0) is used if you want to initialize each field separately, so you don't need it if you want to pass the whole array at once. You could also use `NewRow` and initialize all fields at once with `ItemArray`, but you need multiple lines:

```
DataRow row = dtTable1.NewRow();
row.ItemArray = new object[] { datCol1, string.Join(",", listCol2) };
dtTable1.Rows.Add(row);
```

A third option is to add an empty row and afterwards modify the already added row:

```
DataRow addedRow = dtTable1.Rows.Add();
addedRow.ItemArray = new object[] { datCol1, string.Join(",", listCol2) };
```

Comment: Thanks. The error is having added the NewRow. Just object [] is enough.  dtTable1.Rows.Add(new object[] { datCol1, string.Join(",", listCol2) });

Comment: @user2979594: Yes, so what i have said in my answer in the first sentence :)

Comment: I suppose you realize `Rows.Add` is defined with `params` so you don't need `new object[]`